# VBA - dictionary going through a worksheet holding two values, counting the two values, then splitting the values with a delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

The idea here is that i am having a sheet with more than 80,000 rows and six different columns. what I care about is the 2 columns though. I want the vba to go through each row, get the source IP in column D and the last word in the message box in column F after this "->" symbol, an example of the word is "175.55.78.35:8545". Then once it's done retrieving the values from all the rows, print the results in 3 columns on a new sheet.

NOTE that one IP address can be related with many different words.

What i am looking for, is the vba return the source IP in one column, the last word it found in column F, and the last column should consist of the number the last word in column F was associated with the ip in column D.

[this is how the table looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJWBG.png)

This is what code i have thanks to Jeeped, but the issue is that some source IP addresses end up missing and the count does not seem to be right.

```
  Sub timesofattack2()

Dim data As Variant, dic As Object, k As Long, ks As String

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    data = .Range(.Cells(8, "D"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Value2
End With

For k = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
    ks = Join(Array(data(k, 1), Split(data(k, 3) & "->", "->")(1)), ChrW(8203))
    dic(ks) = dic(ks) + 1
Next

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    .Range("A2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)
    .Range("C2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Items)
    .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Cells(2, "A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=ChrW(8203), _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you comment a little bit what you expect the code to do in the **With 
 Thisworkbook.worksheets.Add** section. Also what is this dic object. You get data you want to map in the new sheet from that object.

Comment: Include a sample few rows of expected output as well.